# How to create a searchable dropdown in UI Grid using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

**I was tried like this, using this simple dropdown will appears**

```
{
               displayName: "Name", name: 'ID', field: 'ID', minWidth: 350,
               editType: 'dropdown',
               editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
               editDropdownOptionsFunction: function (rowEntity, colDef) {
                   return _List;
               },
               cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope">{{grid.appScope.PrintName(row.entity.ID)}}</div>'
}
```